# Toggling package on install and start

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Atom package I'm building to toggle on install and editor start. I'm not sure what to put into the activate function. At the moment you install my package then have to toggle in the command palette. Is there a way to avoid this and to just have Atom toggle the package automatically when installed/enabled

Comment: Hi, what exactly are you trying to achieve with the package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atom uses the `activationCommands` entry in the `package.json` to declare that activation of the package can wait until one of the listed commands is executed. If this entry **does not** exist, then the package will be activated immediately after it is loaded (which is on installation or application start).

The reason why `activationCommands` is highly recommended is that not all packages need to be activated immediately after loading and it is a simple way to reduce Atom's startup time. You can check Atom's startup time with the [timecop package](https://github.com/atom/timecop) by pressing <kbd>Shift+Cmd+P</kbd> on OS X to open the Command Palette and search for `timecop`.